# Git strategy for when you need to work on several features at a time

Tags: git, version-control

Let's say I am working on a few front-end features concurrently that all are in different branches (e.g. `login` branch, `reset` password branch, `update` settings branch, etc.). In our current workflow, it's up to me in which order or manner I finish all these features as long as I do them within the set deadline (e.g. 2 weeks time).

To pace myself better, I'd create a branch for each of these features and work on them concurrently, integrating the functionalities first (the hard parts so to speak) and work on the styles and nitty-gritty details towards the end. (Analogy would be like building a house; you don't really complete each part of the house one by one. You build all the foundation first, scaffolding and all, before you do all the decorative stuff towards the end.)

Now this is fine if all of these features are totally isolated from one another. However, there are functionalities or even general styles that I've done on e.g. `login` branch that I can actually use in `reset` password branch. (Example, both are forms hence should have the same general form styling and will make use of the same validation functions).

However, since all of them are WIP all at once, I cannot do a PR for `login` before I continue working on `reset pw` (e.g. `login` is at 90% and `reset pw` at 80% but I need something from `login` to get `reset pw` to 90% completion also). Even if I complete `login`, PR reviews may take time.

I also cannot also e.g. merge/rebase to `login` from `reset pw` because 1. that would mix the 2 different features and 2. `login` feature is not even approved yet.

What is the best strategy for this kind of scenario? I am in a dilemma because the best way to actually avoid this is to finish one feature after another. But at the same time, I work better if I do it in the manner I just mentioned (in parallel).

Comment: I could suggest things like `git stash` and work trees, but I won't.  The reason I won't is that if you find yourself needing to build the same things for different branches/features, then maybe you have a workflow problem.  See if you can redefine these branches so that they are not so tightly coupled.

Answer (score 6):

This is opinion based but I would work on all these three features on a single branch. e.g. I should be able to `login`. That doesn't require `reset pw`. Once the login feature is done, I push that for code review or whatever. After that, I add the password reset functionality as a different set of commits and send that for review.

The general point is that if the features are coupled, the split is artificial and it's better to treat them as a single branch. If the features are coupled, it's usually still possible to sort them in order of dependency and implement them in order.

Answer (score 6):

Actually you can have one feature after another, that's not a technical impossibility, it only requires a little more work on your part in terms of *knowing* how you have things laid out so that you can move stuff around.

Let's do a little excercise. You have feature1 branch with 2 commits and then your start feature2 *on top* of feature1. You develop a couple of commits on top of feature2. At this point you realize you need to do something on feature 1:

```
git checkout feature1
# edit files
git add blah blah
git commit -m "feature 1"
```

Now, how do you pull this into feature2? Simple enough:

```
git checkout feature2
git rebase feature1
```

That was simple.... At this point you realize that you *also* need something from feature3.. feature 3 has 10 commits and you only need feature3~2. Do *not* put it on top of feature2, because then you are mixing stuff up in history. You would:

```
git checkout HEAD~2 (go back in history 2 revisions... do not use a branch)
git cherry-pick feature3~2 # get the revision you need
# how do we move feature2 onto this?
git rebase --onto HEAD HEAD feature2 # rebase only the last 2 revisions of feature2. No need to rebase any of the revisions up to where you are standing right now
```

Now feature 3 is completely merged into master, and you are asked to move everything on top of current position of master. Well... you are not in charge of feature3 so no point in moving that revision with you, right?

```
git checkout feature1
git rebase master
git rebase --onto feature1 feature2~2 feature2
```

And feature 3 is gone from history. At this point you want to separate feature2 from feature1:

```
git checkout feature2
git rebase --onto master feature2~2 feature2
```

And now feature2 is on top of master and not feature1... and you can see how you were able to move stuff around without too much work.... it's only a matter of knowing how the "branches are laid down", much like a traffic controller with planes.

Answer (score 0):

Do your development work however best suits your development work, then use `git rebase -i`s (or for more wholesale restructuring `git reset` and `git add -p`/`git commit` rebuilds) to construct the commits you would have made in the first place if you'd known exactly what was best all along.

Nobody needs to see your first drafts ... except you. Nobody needs to work with them ... except you.  You've got a world-class vcs at your fingertips, why *not* use Git to help  with your first-draft work?  Use it.  Then use Git to prepare what you've done for publication.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective (and experience), it pays off to merge partial features into master in such scenario. You should be able to extract common parts for e.g. login/password reset, create separate branch for it, create PR, merge and move on. Basically, you branch per building block, not per feature.

If it's blocking you, it's useless to cling on self-imposed limitations such as "feature can be merged into master/develodp/integration branch only when it's fully done". Been there and postponing PRs leads to merge hell and endless comments.